# tensorflow resize image changes color

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my algorithm below, resize_images changes the color of my image to something wrong. why? my image is 375 row 1242 colum 3 channel

```
# Typical setup to include TensorFlow.
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a queue of file names including all the JPEG images files in the relative
# image directory.
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
   tf.train.match_filenames_once("./MNIST_data/*.png"))

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

image_f = tf.image.decode_png(value) # use png or jpg decoder based on your files.
image   = tf.image.resize_images(image_f, [375, 1242])

#Generate batch
# num_preprocess_threads = 1
# min_queue_examples = 256
# batch_size=2;
# images = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    # [image],
    # batch_size=batch_size,
    # num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
    # capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
    # min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)

  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  my_image = image.eval() #here is your image Tensor :) 
  print(my_image.shape)
  fig = plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(my_image)
  plt.show()

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: do you think StackOverflow is some coding service? This is the 6th question you've asked in 2 days!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation of [`tf.resize_images`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image/resizing#resize_images),

> Resized images will be distorted if their original aspect ratio is not the same as size. To avoid distortions see `resize_image_with_crop_or_pad`.

Your aspect ratio is not correct, so due to the distorting the color of image appears to be changing. Use `resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` if you don't want this to happen.

---

Please start reading the documentations. They will answer more than half your questions.

Comment: It's not the resizing at fault. Extending to the below answer, a simple solution is to cast the image to `uint8`. `image = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)` if no preprocessing was done.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

`tf.image.resize` does change the aspect ratio, but this does not effect the colormap. Nor will using `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad`  resolve the color distortion.

The colormap is determined by two rules. If the image values are integers, they use a scale from [0, 255]. If the type is a float, it is mapped from [0.0, 1.0].

When scaling, resize will covert integers to floats, but does not rescale the values. This can result in values from [0.0, 255.0] which throws the colormap out of whack.

To remedy, you can either cast the values back to int or scale the values from [0.0, 1.0] using `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)`.

This is generally a good idea anyway as models tend to handle smaller values better than larger ones and you can scale other features so they are on the same range. Also, casting to integers would lose some small amount of variance.